# Sistemas de votos em urna eletrônica em Java

Tags: java, algoritmo

Estou fazer uma urna eletrônica que cadastre, liste e o usuário consiga votar no candidato, já consigo cadastrar e listar os candidatos, mas como faço para sempre contar +1 em um atributo votos de cada candidato em um `ArrayList`?

```
        ArrayList<Candidato>listacandi;
                    listacandi = new ArrayList<Candidato>();
                    Scanner e= new Scanner(System.in);
                    int op;

        do {
            System.out.println("Cadastrar 1 ");
            System.out.println("Consultar 2");
            op=e.nextInt();

            if (op==1){
                Candidato candidato = new Candidato();

                System.out.println("digite o nome ");
                candidato.setNome(e.next());
                System.out.println("digite o partido");
                candidato.setPartido(e.next());
                System.out.println("digite o numero");
                candidato.setNumero(e.next());

                listacandi.add(candidato);
            }else if (op==2) {
                System.out.println("Digite um numero");
                String n = e.next();

                for (int i =0; i<listacandi.size();i++){
                    if (listacandi.get(i).getNumero().equals(n)){
                        System.out.println(listacandi.get(i).getNome()+","+listacandi.get(i)
                                .getPartido()+",");
                    }
                }
            }else if (op ==3){

            }
        }while (op!=4);
    }
}
```

Classe Candidato

```
public class Candidato {

    String nome;
    String partido;
    String numero;
    int votos=0;

    public int getVotos() {
        return votos;
    }

    public void setVotos( int votos) {
        this.votos = votos;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getPartido() {
        return partido;
    }

    public void setPartido(String partido) {
        this.partido = partido;
    }


}
```

Comment: Adiciona a classe Candidato ao código da pergunta.

Comment: Seria bom pelo menos começar fazer esta parte que está perguntando e ter uma dúvida específica.

Comment: Adicionei  a classe Candidato, tinha esquecido rsrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu ajudaria mais se tivesse fornecido mais. Reestruturei todo o código porque está forma está longe do ideal. Minha versão também não é o ideal, mas para um exercício está bom:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Candidato> Candidatos = new ArrayList<Candidato>();
        Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);
        int op;
        do {
            System.out.println("Cadastrar 1 ");
            System.out.println("Consultar 2");
            System.out.println("Votar     3");
            System.out.println("Finalizar 4");
            op = e .nextInt();
            if (op == 1) {
                System.out.println("digite o numero");
                String numero = e.next();
                System.out.println("digite o nome ");
                String nome = e.next();
                System.out.println("digite o partido");
                String partido = e.next();
                Candidatos.add(new Candidato(numero, nome, partido));
            } else if (op == 2) {
                System.out.println("Digite um numero");
                String n = e.next();
                for (int i = 0; i < Candidatos.size(); i++) {
                    if (Candidatos.get(i).getNumero().equals(n)) {
                        System.out.println(Candidatos.get(i).getNome() + ", " + Candidatos.get(i).getPartido() + ", " + Candidatos.get(i).getVotos());
                    }
                }
            } else if (op == 3) {
                System.out.println("Digite um numero de quem deseja votar");
                String n = e.next();
                int i = 0;
                for (; i < Candidatos.size(); i++) {
                    if (Candidatos.get(i).getNumero().equals(n)) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (i != Candidatos.size()) Candidatos.get(i).Votar();
            }
        } while (op !=4 );
    }
}

class Candidato {
    String nome;
    String partido;
    String numero;
    int votos = 0;
    public Candidato(String numero, String nome, String partido) {
        this.numero = numero;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.partido = partido;
    }
    public void Votar() { votos++; }
    public int getVotos() { return votos; }
    public String getNumero() { return numero; }
    public String getNome() { return nome; }
    public String getPartido() { return partido; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0rEMVo). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bgoccdej-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Election.java).

Na verdade tem várias coisas que estão em local errado, do jeito errado. Curiosamente as pessoas procuram fazer OOP sem entender o que é isto e quase sempre os códigos são bem procedurais.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente amigo, me tirou várias duvidas. Se eu quisesse criar uma opção para alteração de cadastro, eu apenas criaria os setters  certo?

Comment: Sim, mas não faz sentido, um dado como este é imutável, não deveria ser alterado. O problema é justamente as pessoas quererem usar *getters* e *setters*  por padrão sem precisar deles.

Comment: Sim entendi, estou começando em java agora por isso estou com dúvidas ainda.